# Need Menu to Fit 100% of Width of Container

Tags: html, css, wordpress, menu, width

This is my first post and I am hopeful that someone can help me with what I think is probably a very simple problem.

And as a disclaimer I have tried numerous suggestions from here on the site as well as others and can't seem to nail it down.

I have a menu that I need to fill the width of the container/page which is 1080px wide.  I have tried working with the 'width' the 'display' the 'padding' and various other items and just cannot get this figured out.

Before I show the code let me explain one thing.  This is a WordPress site, but I am running a plugin that allows it to run more like a page builder to simplify design.  This page builder plugin is where the custom CSS resides for this menu and it needs to run through this plugin so as to maintain the sites functionality.  It also does not really allow me to access the HTML for this particular element so that is not a viable option.  The CSS needs to be the location for the solution.  I hope that makes sense.

I think that the problem lies with the borders for the menu, which is what the code below references.

The Menu is on this page:
[WeAreOneBodyRadio.org](http://weareonebodyradio.org)

(If you try other links on that page you will get different pages that were designed differently on another platform.  So best to stay on this page.)

CSS:

```
div[data-style='horizontal'] ul.menu > li.menu-item > a, div[data-style='vertical'] ul.menu > li.menu-item > a {
    border: 1px solid #D7AA70;
    border-radius: 0px;
    width: auto;
    padding: 5px 23px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

This actually stems from a larger problem of having the padding originally set to fill the width perfectly, but then on the mobile view of this page (not mobile version, just a mobile view of the full page) it was pushing the width over 1080px by about 0.700 of a pixel and forcing the menu to two lines.

So I thought I would make the menu shorter and try to fill out the width instead of trying to make it smaller.

Please ask any questions and offer any suggestions.  I am not a CSS expert.  I rely on the help I find on places like this great site.  I also do not understand JavaScript/JQuery.  However, if that is the only answer, I will find a way to make it work.

Thanks in advance.  Peace.

Comment: Use chrome developer tools: you can hover over an element and you'll see in a rectangle on the bottom right corner: exactly what padding, margin that element has. Also, most browsers come with a style-preset. So you should look into Reset CSS, and why people use it.

Comment: Hi!  Thanks for the suggestion.  I have however been diligently pouring through the developer tools and watching every little detail as I highlight them.  And when I think I have found a potential for fixing my problem it does not.  And it was using the developer tools that I found that the mobile version's width going over, using the info from the 'computed' column.  Thanks again!

Comment: Not sure I understood the problem. The padding on the `a` inside `li` is what is determining the menu's width. Just switch `padding` to `padding: 5px 24px` on the last element. (To select a last-of-type, use the `:last-child` pseudo-selector). If you want to push it even further out than the above fix. Also add a `margin-left: -3px` to the first `li`, and proceed to increase the `li > a`s `padding`.

Comment: So there was still something that was not quite right using the `:last-child`  It turned out since each `a` was nested in its own `li` element that I could not target it.  So I needed to go after the first `li` element and then the `a:last-child` and it allowed me to adjust the first menu item. So thanks for getting me headed in the right direction.

Comment: I'm glad I could be of service.